# Application missing common mitigation techniques checked using Binscope UWP VAPT

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp

In my VAPT report the following checkpoint got failed for my UWP app.

Application missing common mitigation techniques

[image]

[image]

How can I fix the failed checks?